# Force onDestroy to solve memory problems

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-sdk-2.3

I am facing memory problems in my application, which use a TabHost and TabGroupActivity as TabContent.

I noticed that sometimes the life cycle of Activity is strange.

I start the app, tab1 is loaded and then I click on tab2 (Tab1->Tab2 )

```
Tab1Group.onPause called
Tab1.onPause called

Tab2Group.onCreate called
Tab2.onCreate called
```

Then I return to Tab1 (Tab2->Tab1)

```
Tab2Group.onPause called 
Tab1Group.onDestroy called
Tab1.onDestroy called
Tab1.onCreate called
```

Well, if the tab1 is destoyed when I am back, it would be great to destroy it directly rather than calling `onPause`, so the VM could free more memory.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the intents and null all objects manually

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: not sure how can I do that.. i m using a tabhost so I m not calling startActivity

Comment: I found this as solution @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }